# what is the meaning of this inequality $x\le -5$ in $\mathbb{R} $?

Tags: real-numbers

what is the  meaning of  this inequality  $x\le -5$  in $\mathbb{R} $ ?

I thinks it may look like  this  $-9,-8 -7,-6 \le -5$

i mean $-6 \le -5$ ,

$-7\le-5$.......so on

Is its true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means $x$ can be -5 or a real number less than -5. Can't comment.

Comment: u mean $-2 \le -5?$

Comment: Real number set is a set of elements integers, rational and irrational numbers that are comparable by inequalities.